# Hang with “SYSLINUX 6.04 EDD 6.04-perl Copyright (C) 1994-2015 H. Peter Anvin et al” while boot from bootable usb

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bootable-media

With coreboot BIOS SeaBIOS payload trying to boot to bootable USB but facing hang with message "SYSLINUX 6.04 EDD 6.04-perl Copyright (C) 1994-2015 H. Peter Anvin et al". normal boot works on already install linux OS. any hint to approach this issue will be appreciated.

enabled SeaBIOS debug logs, it continuously dump below message: could it be due to IRQ not set properly?

```
xhci_doorbell: slotid 1, epid 3 xhci_process_events: ring 0x000ea600 [trb 0x000ea660, evt 0x000ea700, type 32, eidx 7, cc 1] 
xhci_poll_intr: st 1000000 ct 1038000 [ 0x000eb9f6 <= 0x4e647fa0 / 8 ] xhci_trb_queue: ring 0x000ea600 [nidx 8, len 8] xhci_doorbell: slotid 1, epid 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the drivers to allow your system to continue reading from the USB are not on the USB.

Have you tried "system rescue cd" instead?  That works on a LOT of systems.

Alternatively, try a few old Ubuntu installer ISOs - I've found those work sometimes when sysresccd does not (e.g. on Macs)

Another option: boot a DVD and install a fresh linux on your USB stick (i.e. don't use an ISO on it)

Comment: enabled SeaBIOS debug logs, it continuously dump below message:              
suspecting IRQ not set correctly..                                                                                                                           

xhci_doorbell: slotid 1, epid 3
xhci_process_events: ring 0x000ea600 [trb 0x000ea660, evt 0x000ea700, type 32, eidx 7, cc 1]
xhci_poll_intr: st 1000000 ct 1038000 [ 0x000eb9f6 <= 0x4e647fa0 / 8 ]
xhci_trb_queue: ring 0x000ea600 [nidx 8, len 8]
xhci_doorbell: slotid 1, epid 3